# Android Textview: (pressed) status auto cleared when a popup, message box displayed, or when loading next activity

Tags: android, textview, selector, status

I am testing a very simple case: an activity has one TextView:

```
`<TextView`<br>
    `android:id="@+id/test"`<br>
`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`<br>
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`<br>
`android:background="@drawable/test_selector"`<br>
`/>`
```

whose selector is defined as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/test_image_unselect"
    android:color="@color/blue" />


    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/test_image_select"
    android:color="@color/white" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/test_image_unselect"
    android:color="@color/blue" />

</selector>
```

The test_image_unselect is an white background image, and the test_image_select is an red background image.

when activity start, set the state of TextView to be pressed

lblTest = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.test);
lblTest.setPressed(true);

And the pressed status is displayed (red background) without any problem.

But when some event happened, like an popup or alert box displayed, the press status is cleared (white background), and event after the popup or alert box closed, the press status is still cleared (white background).

Also, when moving to the next activity, during some mili seconds when the next activity is loading, current activity is still displayed, and the TextView status is also cleared (white background) event it is set to pressed status already.

I did some google search but did not find any reason why.

Looking for help.

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0):

I found that using setSelected can solve the problem.

Pressed status is cleared each time activity on pause or not active, but selected status is not.